# How to prove embedded copies of a curve using different base points in its Jacobian are algebraically equivalent

Tags: algebraic-curves, jacobians, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $k\subset\mathbb{C}$, and $p,q\in X(k)$. Let $X_p$ (resp. $X_q$) be the embedded copy of $X$ in the Jacobian $Jac(X)$ using the base point $p$ (resp. $q$). Is the $1-$cycle $X_p-X_q$ on $Jac(X)$ algebraically zero? How is it proved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathop{\rm Jac}(X)\times X$, consider the cycle $Z=\{(x,p)\,;\, x\in X_p\}$. One has $Z_p=X_p$, $Z_q=X_q$, hence the definition of algebraic equivalence shows that $X_p-X_q$ is algebraically equivalent to $0$.

Comment: Hi. Is $Z_p$ the pullback of $Z$ along the embedding $Jac(X)\rightarrow Jac(X)\times X$ mapping $x\mapsto (x,p)$? Would it not have codimension one more than $X_p$?